# Select tags that start with a specific pattern with JSoup

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

I need to find html tags that starts with a pattern for example, a pattern of a letter 's' would match `<span>`, `<strong>`, etc. using Jsoup. I tried using selectors but they did not seem to work the way I need. I tried various stuff, like `doc.getElementsByTag("s*");` or `doc.getElementsByTag("s[*]");` . Is it at least possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a JSoup selector that will do that (i.e. using patterns).  Check the [javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) for yourself.

The closest I can think of is:

```
doc.select("strong, span");
```

which should give you all of the `<strong>` and `<span>` element in `doc`.    If you have other "s" elements you are interested in you can add them.